# CSS background-image is very picky

Tags: css

I am trying to set my site's background image to a local img through CSS. But the code will not let me use a local image, but a non-local internet image is fine. Why is that?

Code:

```
html {
  /* background-image: url("chrome://global/skin/media/imagedoc-darknoise.png"); */
  background-image: url("img/diamondPlate_bg.jpg");
}
```

The bottom image is the one that should show, but it doesn't. but the top image does work. Why?

Comment: what do you mean it does not let. what happens when you try to add local image. I am sure that css->background image can use local images.

Comment: try absolute or relative paths not chrome:// stuff

Comment: Check for webkit inspector for further details; The resources tab might be telling. I don't have enough information in your post to even begin to speculate about your problem.

Comment: @ThorSummoner, I am trying to use a local image as a background image for my site. Referencing resources online, I say that my code is correct, but it does not work. So I dont know if there is something special needed for local images or if my syntax is off or something entirely else

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the full image path, as the browser can't determine where to search for.

Comment: I tried _background-image: url("C:\Users\YAZAN\Documents\My Website\imgdiamondPlate_bg.jpg");_ and it still isnt working. I would assume its something to do with escape characters, but I'm not very familiar with how CSS does escape characters

Comment: @yazan Try adding *file://* , and change the backwards slashes into forward slashes. As follows:  background-image: url('file:///C://Users/YAZAN/Documents/My Website/imgdiamondPlate_bg.jpg');

Answer (score 1):

According to your CSS file path, I will suppose it is at the img directory with your HTML page, you have to change the url as follows:

```
body { 
    background: url("../img/diamondPlate_bg.jpg") repeat 0 0;
}
```

This is like going back one folder and entering the img folder to fetch images.